# How do I position unordered lists (nav menu) inside width: 100% div?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, unordered

EDIT: Fixed, unconventially (I think), all I did was margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto, the nav menu, and gave it a fixed width of my liking (1002px, in my case), and made the positioning relative, and created another div which had a 'mock' background, and made it absolute. Thanks to the guys that offered solutions though, appreciate it.

Was wondering if anyone could help me with this problem. Currently designing a website, where the nav menu div doesn't have a fixed width (width: 100%), and inside this nav menu div are the unordered lists "Home | About | Services | Gallery | Contact". So the problem is, when I preview my website in a browser, the "Home | About etc." floats to the left, and when I scroll out, making the page smaller, it continues floating left. So my question, without having to fix the width of the div, would anyone happen to know how to position these unordered lists, so that it is flush or in line with the rest of my page/content.

heres the css for the navigation menu:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#navigation {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(../pictures/nav_bg.jpg);
}
#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation li {
    float: left;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 88px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../pictures/nav_button.jpg);
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-image:url(../pictures/nav_button_hover.jpg)
}
```

Comment: a little preview will be alot useful for us

Comment: yeah sorry, let me get something for you

Comment: there you go, sorry about that lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HBXku/32/)

Use the following code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.nav {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#62564A;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
}
.nav li { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:19%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav a {
    text-align:center;
    padding:12px 0 13px 0;
    margin:0;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    display:block;
}
.nav a:hover { 
    background:#A26A42;
    border:none;
}

ul.nav li:first-child a{
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
ul.nav li:last-child a {
border:none;
}
```